# Deleting duplicate data in one of three column in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I tried to use some functions that I found whilst searching to solve my problem, they are slightly modified it to remove duplicate data in a field. 
[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0LiO.png)

Rather than a count of 4, I would like the count of 2 from column J. The information below are my attempts for 4 different sections on the attached document as I always thought the next one would give me the result that I wanted.

> H  ====I==========J
>   P13C   Body Exterior   4943
>
> P13C   Body Exterior   4943
>
> P13C   Body Exterior   5122
>
> P13C   Body Exterior   5122
>
> =IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$142,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS($H$7:$H$142,B14,$K$7:$K$142,$E$14),0)),"")
>
> as does this
>
> =IFERROR(INDEX($J$7:$J$142,MATCH(,IF(H$7:H$142="P13C",COUNTIF(I7:I142,$J$7:$J$142)),)),"")

and this

> =IFERROR(INDEX($K$7:$K$142,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($H$7:$H$142,$K$7:$K$142),0)),"")

This, gives me a 0

> =IF($J$7:$J$142>1,IF($K$7:$K$142="20",SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($H$7:$H$142,$H$7:$H$142)>1,1))))

This gives me a DIV error

> =SUMPRODUCT(((H7:H142="P13C")*(I7:I142="Body Exterior"))/(COUNTIFS(J7:J142, J7:J142, H7:H142, "P13C", I7:I142,"Body Exterior")+((H7:H142<>"P13C")+(I7:I142="Body Exterior"))))

There are duplicates in `$J$7:$J$142`, but I only want the one count.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the column J in smallest to largest order
2. concatenate all three values by using '&' on next column K ---> `H&I&J`
3. then use `IF` and `COUNTIF` formula on next column L,

Column L:

```
=IF(K1=K2,COUNTIF(K1,K1:K142),"")
```

this a easy method to get count 1 for J column